# Refactoring HTML Markup from POST to GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, forms, http-get

I have the following mark up in an ASP.NET MVC view (this is a [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) search box):

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Results", "Search")" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="search-query" id="SearchTerm" name="SearchTerm" />
</form>
```

This code works as expected, but using a post here is causing problems.

How can I change this markup to pass the search query as a URL argument instead? I'm not really sure how to even approach this short of keeping the existing markup and then redirecting from the controller. I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way than that.

Comment: If you make method="get", doesn't it naturally pass the searchterm value in the querystring?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what problems are you experiencing with a post operation?

Comment: @JonathanWood You should look into the PRG pattern. Post, Redirect, Get. Or you could always POST using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change `method="post"` to `method="get"` and get the desired result.  The form, with a get method setting, pushes the fields in the form to the querystring by its default behavior.

As a workaround, if the default behavior doesn't suit you, you could catch the submit event of the form, and do:

```
window.location = form.action + "?SearchTerm=" + document.getElementById("SearchTerm").value
```

Something like that, where form is a reference to the form element.  You can build the link and redirect using javascript, which is a get request.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly and required no further changes. Thanks.